# How to Associate and Insert Multiple Predetermined MySQL Fields to Single Select Dropdown Option

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating a form update process where I am using PHP to insert multiple values into a MySQL database.  I have it set up to where I am able to manually enter into a specific RecordID and also select the Gender and the EventName.

These RecordIDs should be locked to a specific Gender and EventName, but now you have to manually enter the information correctly.

I am wanting to eliminate the RecordID as a select option and just pick the Gender and EventName, and it will enter the following form input information into the specific RecordID associated with that Gender and EventName.

I've been able to set up a manual process. However, I do not have the foggiest idea how to set up the forced association.  I have also looked into multiple entries into MySQL, but I already understand how to do that.

My HTML:

```
<form action="swimming-world-records-update.php" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ID">ID:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter ID">
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gender">Gender:</label><br>
            <select name="gender">
                <option value="Men">Men</option>
                <option value="Women">Women</option>
                <option value="Mixed">Mixed</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="event">Event:</label><br>
            <select name="event">
                <option value="50m freestyle">50m freestyle</option>
                <option value="100m freestyle">100m freestyle</option>
                <option value="200m freestyle">200m freestyle</option>
                <option value="400m freestyle">400m freestyle</option>
                <option value="800m freestyle">800m freestyle</option>
                <option value="1500m freestyle">1500m freestyle</option>
                <option value="50m backstroke">50m backstroke</option>
                <option value="100m backstroke">100m backstroke</option>
                <option value="200m backstroke">200m backstroke</option>
                <option value="50m breaststroke">50m breaststroke</option>
                <option value="100m breaststroke">100m breaststroke</option>
                <option value="200m breaststroke">200m breaststroke</option>
                <option value="50m butterfly">50m butterfly</option>
                <option value="100m butterfly">100m butterfly</option>
                <option value="200m butterfly">200m butterfly</option>
                <option value="200m IM">200m IM</option>
                <option value="400m IM">400m IM</option>
                <option value="400m freestyle relay">400m freestyle relay</option>
                <option value="800m freestyle relay">800m freestyle relay</option>
                <option value="400m medley relay">400m medley relay</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

My Function:

```
function updateRecords() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        global $connection;
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $eventname = $_POST['event'];
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $nation = $_POST['nation'];     
        $sname = $_POST['sname'];
        $sdate = $_POST['sdate'];
        $smeet = $_POST['smeet'];
        $smeetlocation = $_POST['smeetlocation'];
        $nation = $_POST['nation'];
        $recordvideo = $_POST['recordvideo'];               
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $gender);
        $eventname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $eventname);
        $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $time);
        $nation = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $nation);
        $sname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $sname);
        $sdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $sdate);
        $smeet = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $smeet);
        $smeetlocation = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $smeetlocation);
        $nation = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $nation);
        $recordvideo = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $recordvideo);
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $id);

        $query = "UPDATE `records` SET ";
        $query .= "Gender = '$gender', ";
        $query .= "EventName = '$eventname', ";
        $query .= "Time = '$time', ";
        $query .= "NationName = '$nation', ";
        $query .= "SwimmerName = '$sname', ";
        $query .= "Date = '$sdate', ";  
        $query .= "MeetName = '$smeet', ";
        $query .= "MeetLocation = '$smeetlocation', ";
        $query .= "VideoURL = '$recordvideo' ";
        $query .= "WHERE RecordID = $id ";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if(!$result) {
                die("Query failed." . mysqli_error($connection));
            } else {
                echo "Record updated!";
            }
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to select Gender Event in a dropdown, and it will only UPDATE into the locked associated RecordID.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation points to comment yet. There needs to be some way to reference your `record_id` during the `POST`. If you do not want to do that, then you will need to execute a `SELECT` statement using the `Gender` and `Event` values to get the `record_id` however, if you're updating the `record_id`, then you will not be able to use those values. So, I go back to me initial statement. You need to send the `record_id` in the `POST` request to use as a reference. You cannot just select a `Gender` and `Event` to update an existing `record` but not have a reference for the `record` which to update.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate it.  I finally figured it out with an if elseif setup that worked!

Answer (score 0):

A mentor of mine gave me a heads up.  This actually worked pretty well.

```
if ($gender == "Men" && $eventname == "50m freestyle") {
            $id = "1";
            $gender = "Men";
        } else if ($gender == "Men" && $eventname == "100m freestyle") {
            $id = "2";
            $gender = "Men";
```

and so on and so forth.  This set the $id before I had the $query run in the function.

Comment: If the application is database driven then this is an absolutely terrible approach because it's hard coded. You need to be able to reference the `record_id` without hard coding `if` statements.